# Combining two solutions in one using cmake

Tags: c++, qt, cmake, vtk

I have two seperate Visual Studio 2013 solutions  and I want to migrate them into one single solution since the first solution (using Qt) serves as the GUI for the second solution.

At the end I would like to have a single solution with a structure like this:

```
--Solution
-------All Build
-------Project 1
----------------External Dependencies
----------------header files
----------------Source files 
-------Project 2
----------------External Dependencies
----------------header files
----------------Source files
```

The `CMakeLists.txt` for the first project is:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8.5 FATAL_ERROR)
if(POLICY CMP0025)
  cmake_policy(SET CMP0025 NEW) # CMake 3.0
endif()
if(POLICY CMP0053)
  cmake_policy(SET CMP0053 NEW) # CMake 3.1
endif()

project (Project1)

set(CMAKE_MODULE_PATH 
    ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/CMake
)

find_package(VTK REQUIRED)
include(${VTK_USE_FILE})

find_package(OpenVR REQUIRED)
find_package(SDL2 REQUIRED)

include_directories(${OPENVR_INCLUDE_DIRS})
include_directories(${SDL2_INCLUDE_DIR})
include_directories(${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR})

set(HEADER_FILES
    ...
)

set(CODE_FILES
    ...
)


# Copy the obj file to the build directory
file(COPY Data/***.*** DESTINATION ${PROJECT_BINARY_DIR}/Data)
file(COPY Data/***.*** DESTINATION ${PROJECT_BINARY_DIR}/Data)
file(COPY Data/***.*** DESTINATION ${PROJECT_BINARY_DIR}/Data)

#QT5_ADD_RESOURCES(visualization_RCS resources.qrc)

if(VTK_LIBRARIES)
add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME} ${CODE_FILES} ${HEADER_FILES})
  target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} ${VTK_LIBRARIES} ${SDL2_LIBRARY})  
else()
  message("Specific Libs")
endif()
```

The `CMakeLists.txt` for the second project is:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8.12)
project(Project2)
find_package(Qt5Widgets)
set(MyProjectLib_src ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/gui.cpp)
set(MyProjectLib_hdr ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/gui.h)
set(MyProjectLib_ui  ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/gui.ui)
set(MyProjectBin_src ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/main.cpp)
qt5_wrap_cpp(MyProjectLib_hdr_moc ${MyProjectLib_hdr})
qt5_wrap_ui (MyProjectLib_ui_moc  ${MyProjectLib_ui})
include_directories(${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR})
include_directories(${PROJECT_BINARY_DIR})
add_library(MyProjectLib STATIC 
    ${MyProjectLib_src}
    ${MyProjectLib_hdr_moc}
    ${MyProjectLib_ui_moc}
)
target_link_libraries(MyProjectLib Qt5::Widgets)
add_executable(MyProject ${MyProjectBin_src})
target_link_libraries(MyProject MyProjectLib)
```

The thing is that i am not able to combine the two `CMakeLists.txt` into one file. I am stock at this code since days

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8.12 FATAL_ERROR)
if(POLICY CMP0025)
  cmake_policy(SET CMP0025 NEW) # CMake 3.0
endif()
if(POLICY CMP0053)
  cmake_policy(SET CMP0053 NEW) # CMake 3.1
endif()

project (project1)

set(CMAKE_MODULE_PATH 
    ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/CMake
)

find_package(VTK REQUIRED)
include(${VTK_USE_FILE})

find_package (Qt5Widgets REQUIRED)
find_package(OpenVR REQUIRED)
find_package(SDL2 REQUIRED)

include_directories(${OPENVR_INCLUDE_DIRS})
include_directories(${SDL2_INCLUDE_DIR})
include_directories(${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR})

set(HEADER_FILES
    GPU/header.h
    ...
    ...
)

set(CODE_FILES
    GPU/sourcefile.cxx
    ...
)


#QT5_ADD_RESOURCES(visualization_RCS resources.qrc)
project (project2)


find_package (Qt5Widgets)


set (GuiLib_src Gui/gui.cpp)
set (GuiLib_hdr Gui/gui.h)
set (GuiLib_ui  Gui/gui.ui)
set (GuiBin_src Gui/main.cpp)


qt5_wrap_cpp(GuiLib_hdr_moc ${GuiLib_hdr})
qt5_wrap_ui (GuiLib_ui_moc  ${GuiLib_ui})


include_directories (${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR})
include_directories (${PROJECT_BINARY_DIR})


add_library (GuiLib STATIC 
    ${GuiLib_src}
    ${GuiLib_hdr_moc}
    ${GuiLib_ui_moc}
)
target_link_libraries (GuiLib Qt5::Widgets)



if(VTK_LIBRARIES)
  add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME} ${CODE_FILES} ${HEADER_FILES})
  target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} ${VTK_LIBRARIES} ${SDL2_LIBRARY})  #Qt5::Core Qt5::Gui
  add_executable(Gui ${GuiBin_src})
  target_link_libraries (Gui GuiLib)
else()
  message("Specific Libs")
endif()
```

It is worth mentioning that `project1` is using VTK, OpenVR and SDL, while `project2` is just using Qt 5.

Comment: Would it be an option for you to leave the two `CMakeLists.txt` files intact, and just add a parent which will do two `add_directory()` calls?

Comment: Just move external feature by external feature, then sub-folder by sub-folder. I don't get the actual question.

Comment: @Angew could you please provide a code example

Comment: Can you post what your pre-migration `CMakeLists.txt` files look like? I assume you have one for each "solution," (since you talk about combining them), so please post them. It'll be easier to formulate with them.

Comment: You have lot of redundancy in your cmake file (two calls to `project` command, `find_package(Qt5Widgets)` called twice, `VTK_LIBRARIES` tested in if-statement while you marked VTK as required, ...). Apart from that, what's wrong with your combined CMakeLists? Do you have any errors? What kind of help are you asking here?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The easiest solution to satisfy the requirements you have outlined in the question is to introduce a new CMakeList file in `Solution/CMakeLists.txt`:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8.12)
project(NameForTheCombinedProject)

add_subdirectory(path/to/project1/dir)
add_subdirectory(path/to/project2/dir)
```

In addition, you'll have to change all references to `CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR` and `CMAKE_BINARY_DIR` in the projects to `CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR` and `CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR`, respectively. In particular, this affects the commands `set(CMAKE_MODULE_PATH ...)` and `file(COPY ...)` in Project 1.

The reason is that now `CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR`and `CMAKE_BINARY_DIR` will refer to the directories of the toplevel (newly created) project.

Comment: both project1 and project2 seperatly are genereated without errors. but when i do the suggested answer I get error where i should provide OpenVRConfig.cmake directory.

Comment: @test11 I didn't notice you were using buildsystem-global paths; answer updated.